# How to change the tab names?

Tags: android-studio, android-adapter, android-tablayout, settext

I'm currently working on a mobile app as a final project in my course. I have this screen that has TabLayout inside in it. My problem is they have the same tab name. I want them to have different names. Where should I change the

ADAPTER

```
package com.example.biowit;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class LoginAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {


public LoginAdapter(@NonNull  FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    super(fragmentActivity);
}

public LoginAdapter(@NonNull  Fragment fragment) {
    super(fragment);
}

public LoginAdapter(@NonNull  FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull  Lifecycle lifecycle) {
    super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {

    switch (position){

        case 0:
            LoginTabFragment loginTab = new LoginTabFragment();
            return loginTab;
        case 1:
            SignupTabFragment signupTab = new SignupTabFragment();
            return signupTab;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return 2; }
}
```

SCREEN

```
package com.example.biowit;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator;

public class
LoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 viewPager;
    float v=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        
        LoginAdapter login_adapter = new LoginAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(login_adapter);
        
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
                new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull  TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                        tab.setText("LOGIN");
                    }
                }).attach();
        tabLayout.setAlpha(v);
    }
}
```

[image: Here's the problem (picture)]

Comment: There is an incomplete sentence in this post, "Where should I change the". Could you edit the question to complete it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your desired tab name in `onConfigureTab` method:

```
new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
        new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull  TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        tab.setText("LOGIN");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tab.setText("SIGNUP");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }).attach();
```